# Bootstrap div In container won't go to 100% size

Tags: html, css

I have a `div.row2` that I'm trying to make fit the whole page and it's not working.

I have a container-fluid that is the container for the whole site. Inthere there's a container that is used to keep a certain section in place.

Here's the overall structure in HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-static-top">
<div class="container"> <!-- this container is only meant to apply to the navbar-->
```

This is crucial:

- **Anything** that is inside the container at the TOP OF THE PAGE is scaled to full width.
- **However,** trying to wrap a container around this `div` further down the page DOES NOT work. In fact it makes the div come out even narrower.
- Including this `div` in the container further UP the page on the other hand does work (in terms of the width), but it results in the `div` being pushed further up the page than I want it positioned.
- The way I managed to get the `header` to go to full width was to class it as `navbar-static-top`. But when I look at it's css nothing seems to achieve the same effect for my row2.

All relevant HTML:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav-justified">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 alpha">
  <div class="headline1">
  <div class="col-md-4 alpha">
   <h1>....<h1><br>
 <p class="arial">....</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 beta">
<img src='images/appleproducts/appleproducts.png'/>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<h1 class="hblack">...</h1><br>
<div class="row" style="text-align: center">
<p class="narrow">Lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem lorem ipsem </p>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <img src="images/icons/iphone26.svg" alt="" style="width: 30%; height: 30%; color: #CC6699;">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="images/icons/iphone26.svg" alt="" style="width: 30%; height: 30%;"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="images/icons/iphone26.svg" alt="" style="width: 30%; height: 30%;">
</div>

</div>

<div class="row2" style="text-align: center;">

 <!--this is the offending div-->
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html {
font-family: Impact;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container-fluid {
padding-right: 0%;
padding-left: 0%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 100%;
}

.col-md-12 {
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.row2 {  
background-color: #CC6699;
height: 22%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-radius: 0;
}
```

Just a few things to note:

- I'm fairly certain I've tried all the obvious tricks here: changing `row2` to something different (i.e. `col-md-12`), giving row 2 a `container-fluid`, making sure there's nothing wrapping `row2` except for a `container-fluid`, taking padding off of basically everything, taking margin off of things. And yes, that includes body and html. There's something floating around on bootstrap.css that really wants to keep this `div` less than 100% width but I can't figure out what it is.
- The extremely strange part is that it's almost certainly NOT padding on a containing `div`. I've set padding on `body`, `html`, `container-fluid`, `col-md-12`, and `container` to 0.

  - I've also made everything 100% width where possible.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding the html when I'm reading it. Are you able to use something like bootply.com to mock up what you currently have? It will help me see what we are aiming for

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
body, html { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; overflow: hidden; }
```

`vw` and `vh` ([viewport width and viewport height](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design)) are measurement units that represent 1 = 1% of the viewport. So `100vw` means `100%` of viewport and `100vh` means `100%` of the viewport height. When you use `100%`, it means that the element is `100%` of it's **parent**(i.e. containing element or the element that contains the element in question). Now all of your elements that are **direct descendants** (children) of `body`, will really be `100%` of the viewport.

Comment: This change had an effect, the element got wider (and for some reason moved to the right so it's no longer centered) but it's still not quite 100%.

EDIT: so after untold hours I finally managed to get this to work. What I did was I combed over the HTML and realized that there was a misplaced closing div tag that was causing row2 to be "contained" inside col-md-12. When I fixed that and added "clear:both;" to row2, the problem was solved!

Comment: @AndrewButton Add `</div>` before the closing `</body>` tag.  Also correct the closing `<h1>` to `</h1>` LOL I didn't see your post until I finished mine :P